# When opening files from Excel though OneDrive, a separate dialog box opens and freezes Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-powerpoint, office365, onedrive

A person in my company uses OneDrive to store her files. When opening an Office file like Excel, it will open a transparent dialog box and that cannot be closed and the Excel file cannot by modified or closed. Opening the file through File Explorer or through Excel causes the same issue. 
Happens in Word and PowerPoint as well.

When I download the file from the web version of OneDrive to the Downloads Folder, it opens up with no problem and no secondary box. Open a web version of the Excel file works fine and be modified and such. Only happens when opening it through File Explorer or Excel.

Error then pop ups and reads, "You cannot close Microsoft Excel because a dialog box is open. Click OK, switch to Microsoft Excel, and then close the dialog box"

Only option to close Excel is through Task Manager. 
I am not sure if it is a local issue with the PC or a server/Internet related issue.
Any suggestions?

All other questions that I found online are *similar* but none state that they open from OneDrive.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/office-apps-crash-after-you-try-to-access-files-from-onedrive-46e4c42a-1e4e-45ff-bf67-cd2b4f0f2629

Answer (score 0):

Clearly there's a problem with the dialog window not being loaded completely, but my guess is that this is a confirmation box triggered by an attempt to open a file from an online location. Therefore, a workaround you might try would be to prevent this dialog window completely by adding your online OneDrive domain to Trusted Sites.
To do that, go to Internet Options (part of the Control Panel, also accessible from the Internet Explorer) and add the domain part of the path as a trusted site there. Currently (in my case at least) this would be: https://d.docs.live.net for Personal OneDrive. For a business OneDrive service this would be something like https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com, where "yourdomain" needs to be replaced by your particular setup.